# Make the copy of multidimensional arraylist of floats

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, multidimensional-array, copy

today during debugging of my app I found an issue in my `<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>>`.

My goal is to make a full copy of that ArrayList because now when I change something in the copy of the ArrayList, it makes a change in the original ArrayList too.

So I have something Like this

```
            var first = ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>>()
            var second = ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>()
            var third = ArrayList<Float>()

            for(j in allData) {
                first.add(j.clone() as ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>)
                for(k in j)
                {
                    second.add(k.clone() as ArrayList<Float>)
                    for(l in k)
                    {
                        third.add(l.toFloat())
                    }
                }
            }
            normalizedAllData = first.clone() as ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>>
```

Where `normalizedAllData` is `<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>>`

How should I create a full copy so the new ArrayList will not point to the original ArrayList?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the `Floats` because they are immutable.

You can use nested `map` calls to create copies of the lists, and wrap the results in `ArrayList` constructors:

```
val normalizedAllData = ArrayList(allData.map { innerList ->
    ArrayList(innerList.map { ArrayList(it) })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would resolved the issue in the following simple way:

I will create one helper method:

```
fun flattenList(nestedList: List<Any?>, flatList: MutableList<Any?>) {
    nestedList.forEach { e ->
        when (e) {
            !is List<Any?> -> flatList.add(e)
            else -> flattenList(e, flatList)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I would use this method:

```
// some sample list
val nestedList = arrayListOf(arrayListOf(arrayListOf(1f, 2f, 3f, 4f)))

// contain the flat list
val flatList = mutableListOf<Any?>()

flattenList(nestedList, flatList)

println("Nested    : " + nestedList)
println("Flat    : " + flatList)
```

**Output:**

```
Nested  : [[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]]
Flat    : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

You can use **flattenList()** method for any type:
Another sample:

```
val nestedList = listOf(
        null,
        1f,
        listOf(2.0),
        listOf(listOf(3.0, 4), 5.0),
        listOf(listOf(listOf<String>("Hello Worlds"))),
        listOf(listOf(listOf(6), "seven")),
        "eight",
        listOf<Long>()
    )
val flatList = mutableListOf<Any?>()

flattenList(nestedList, flatList)

println("Nested    : " + nestedList)
println("Flat    : " + flatList)
```

**Output:**

```
Nested  : [null, 1.0, [2.0], [[3.0, 4], 5.0], [[[Hello Worlds]]], [[[6], seven]], eight, []]
Flat    : [null, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4, 5.0, Hello Worlds, 6, seven, eight]
```